# How does parity work for the electric field and electric dipole and electric quadrapole transitions?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, symmetry, atomic-physics, parity

It is known that the electric field is a (polar) vector and is odd under parity. Likewise, when an atom undergoes a dipole transition its parity must flip because the dipole electric field acts like an odd parity. But, if the atom undergoes a quadrapole transition, its parity must stay the same.

How do we reconcile the fact that $E$ is a regular vector with the fact that a quadrapole transition need not change atomic parity?

An answer with equations and clear instructions for how to calculate parity of different "things" would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The electric quadrupole operator is quadratic in position:

$$ Q_{jk}^{(i \rightarrow f)} = \langle i|r_jr_k-\frac 1 3 r^2\delta_{jk}|f\rangle$$

so it's even.

Comment: What would the story be for magnetic quadrupole field then which is also quadratic in position (but odd overall)?

Comment: @Jagerber48 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65074/what-is-the-magnetic-quadrupole-operator