# Have the values of constants ever changed before?

Tags: physical-constants

Example sub-questions:

- Was the speed of light always that value?
- Was the acceleration due to gravity always been 9.8m/s/s?
- Etc

By "change" I mean both actual change in the physical world because of multiple factors and "change" in the numerical value (because the initial value discovered was not precise or accurate).

Comment: 9.8 m/s only applies at the earth's surface. It is different everywhere else. In fact it goes down as you climb up a mountain. The Oklo nuclear reactor indicates there has been no change in the strength of electromagnetic forces (the fine structure constant) in the last 2 billion years. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_nuclear_fission_reactor

Comment: There has obviously been change in the measured values of constants. For example the [first measurement of $c$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B8mer%27s_determination_of_the_speed_of_light) was 26% too low, which was actually pretty good given the measurement was made in 1676.

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate: [Cases of any known fundamental physical constants changing within our locality?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11584/).

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21721/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Futurama GAVE you the answer - "Speed of light was maximum speed until scientist increased it".

Answer (score 3):

Look to large redshift values with the Hubble telescope.  Then do spectroscopy.  Primary physical constants have not changed within visible time within experimental error - more than 14 significant figures for the hydrogen atom hyperfine transition.  Look up the half-life of that spin flip, then Heisenberg for slop in the gears.

Terrestrial acceleration due to gravity is not a constant,

http://www.splung.com/content/sid/2/page/gravitation 
http://www.typnet.net/Essays/EarthGrav.htm 
bottom

Big G is a universal constant.  It is the worst-measured physical constant, upon which all gravitation hinges.  Even worse, the very modest accuracy values substantially diverge - and don't grow better over the years,

http://iopscience.iop.org/0957-0233/10/6/001 
1999
http://www.nature.com/news/2010/100823/full/4661030a.html 
2010